# What are the differences between these two lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
friends = my[:] #1
friends[:] = my #2
```

both variables can be list or string, i.e. iterable. I am learning python.

1. I don't understand how these lines work. Can you explain more about them please?
2. What are the differences between the two lines?

Comment: For line 2, `friends` actually can't be a string. I tried it and got `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line *rebinds* `friends` to a new sequence that is a shallow copy of `my` (really, it can do anything, but assuming `my` isn't a `memoryview` or a weird third party type like a `numpy` array, that's usually a shallow copy of the whole sequence).

The second line *reassigns* the *contents* of `friends` (which must be mutable) to whatever is in the iterable `my` (again, weird overrides of `friends` can change this); `my` need not be a sequence, a plain iterator would also work, and would be exhausted in the process of populating `friends`.

In both cases it's a shallow copy (reassigning or appending/popping elements in `my` after either line won't change `friends`). The main difference is that the first line is a rebinding to a new sequence, while the latter changes `friends` in place. This is important in two ways:

1. Aliasing: If any other name is bound to the same sequence as `friends`, the first option doesn't affect the alias (rebinding discards the old reference, so the other aliases keep it, `friends` doesn't), while the second option modifies the other aliases
2. Type preservation: The second option doesn't change the type of `friends`, it just replaces the contents. The first option doesn't care what `friends` used to be (it could be a non-sequence like `int`), it ends up as whatever the slicing produces (e.g. if `my` is a `list`, `friends` becomes a `list` afterward).

A concrete example using this setup:

```
friends = [1, 2, 3]
alsofriends = friends
my = (4, 5, 6)
```

If you use line 1, then after that line, `friends` is `(4, 5, 6)`, and `alsofriends` is still `[1, 2, 3]` (it's not related to `friends` anymore).

If you use line 2, then after that line, `friends` is `[4, 5, 6]` (contents from `my`, but still a `list`), and `alsofriends` is now `[4, 5, 6]` as well (it's still an alias of `friends`, and the contents of the shared `list` now match what was copied from `my`).